# Don't understand how this summation of complex numbers returns a single value

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I have the equation that gets a height for a vector $ x $ over time $t$:
$$h(\mathbf x,t)=\sum_{\mathbf k}\tilde h(\mathbf k,t)\exp(i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf x)$$
Function $\tilde{h}$  is defined as:
$$\tilde{h} (\mathbf k,t)=\tilde h_0(\mathbf k)\exp(i\omega(k)t)+\tilde h_0^*(-\mathbf k)\exp(-i\omega(k)t)$$
Where:
$$\tilde h_0(\mathbf k)=\frac1{\sqrt2}(\xi_r+i\xi_i)\sqrt{P_h(\mathbf k)}$$
But I do not understand how this returns a single height value, since $\tilde h$ is the sum of a complex number and its conjugate, how then does this sum to a single height value for $x,t$?

Comment: What do you mean by "sum to a single height value"?

Comment: h(x,t) gives a height value for a vector x, at time t. The summation is adding the result of h~(k,t) which is defined as a sum of complex numbers.. so how can a sum of complex numbers return a height value which is a real number scalar quantity ?

Comment: I can't really follow your question very well, but a sum of a complex number and its conjugate is always a real number. Do you refer to that when saying "single height value"?

Comment: $(1+2i)+(3-2i) =4$

Comment: Ohh so complex + conjugate is the sum of the real parts... that explains a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any complex number $z = a+ib$, with $a,b\in\mathbb R$, and its complex conjugate $\bar{z} = a-ib$. Then

$$z+\bar{z} = a+ib+a-ib = 2a$$

which is a real number.

Comment: One question though in the equation in my question the conjugate function takes the negative k vector. Does that still guarantee to the imaginary number cancels out ?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to say for sure what's gonna happen, because there is *a lot* of notation in your question that I'm not sure what exactly means. Try to calculate the two terms in the $\bar{h}(\boldsymbol{k},t)$ separately and see if their imaginary parts would cancel.